# How to refer a Spinner entry correctly?

Tags: java, android, spinner, listeners

I've been making an app for Android which uses a Spinner list to show the name of a few cities. I need the program to change the TextView right below the spinner to display the location of the selected item in the array. I wrote the following code for the same

```
public class MainScreen extends Activity {
String[] cityArray = { "Agra ", "Ahmedabad", "Alappuzha", "Amritsar"};
Spinner list = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.ListView1);
TextView nam = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView2);

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
      super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
      setContentView(R.layout.activity_main_screen);

      ArrayAdapter adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.activity_listview, cityArray);
      list.setAdapter(adapter);


list.setOnItemSelectedListener(new OnItemSelectedListener() {

    @Override
    public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parentView, View view,int position, long id) 
    {
        nam.setText(list.getSelectedItemPosition());
    }

    @Override
    public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {
        nam.setText("None Selected");
    }

});
}
}
```

There are no errors while running the program, but the app simply force closes as soon as it is opened.

Logcat:

```
04-10 08:49:30.423: I/dalvikvm(561): threadid=3: reacting to signal 3
04-10 08:49:30.723: I/dalvikvm(561): Wrote stack traces to '/data/anr/traces.txt'
04-10 08:49:30.783: I/dalvikvm(561): threadid=3: reacting to signal 3
04-10 08:49:30.823: D/AndroidRuntime(561): Shutting down VM
04-10 08:49:30.823: W/dalvikvm(561): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x409c01f8)
04-10 08:49:30.844: E/AndroidRuntime(561): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
04-10 08:49:30.844: E/AndroidRuntime(561): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo{com.droidrish.droidweather/com.droidrish.droidweather.MainScreen}: java.lang.NullPointerException
04-10 08:49:30.844: E/AndroidRuntime(561):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1880)
04-10 08:49:30.844: E/AndroidRuntime(561):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1981)
04-10 08:49:30.844: E/AndroidRuntime(561):  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:123)
04-10 08:49:30.844: E/AndroidRuntime(561):  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1147)
04-10 08:49:30.844: E/AndroidRuntime(561):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
04-10 08:49:30.844: E/AndroidRuntime(561):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
04-10 08:49:30.844: E/AndroidRuntime(561):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4424)
04-10 08:49:30.844: E/AndroidRuntime(561):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
04-10 08:49:30.844: E/AndroidRuntime(561):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
04-10 08:49:30.844: E/AndroidRuntime(561):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:784)
04-10 08:49:30.844: E/AndroidRuntime(561):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:551)
04-10 08:49:30.844: E/AndroidRuntime(561):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
04-10 08:49:30.844: E/AndroidRuntime(561): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
04-10 08:49:30.844: E/AndroidRuntime(561):  at android.app.Activity.findViewById(Activity.java:1794)
04-10 08:49:30.844: E/AndroidRuntime(561):  at com.droidrish.droidweather.MainScreen.<init>(MainScreen.java:15)
04-10 08:49:30.844: E/AndroidRuntime(561):  at java.lang.Class.newInstanceImpl(Native Method)
04-10 08:49:30.844: E/AndroidRuntime(561):  at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:1319)
04-10 08:49:30.844: E/AndroidRuntime(561):  at android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity(Instrumentation.java:1023)
04-10 08:49:30.844: E/AndroidRuntime(561):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1871)
04-10 08:49:30.844: E/AndroidRuntime(561):  ... 11 more
04-10 08:49:30.844: I/dalvikvm(561): Wrote stack traces to '/data/anr/traces.txt'
04-10 08:49:31.416: I/dalvikvm(561): threadid=3: reacting to signal 3
04-10 08:49:31.443: I/dalvikvm(561): Wrote stack traces to '/data/anr/traces.txt'
04-10 08:49:31.583: I/dalvikvm(561): threadid=3: reacting to signal 3
04-10 08:49:31.603: I/dalvikvm(561): Wrote stack traces to '/data/anr/traces.txt'
04-10 08:49:33.722: I/Process(561): Sending signal. PID: 561 SIG: 9
```

Am I using the OnItemSelected Listener the right way? I'm expecting the program to change the text of the TextView to the location of the item in the Spinner.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Spinner and textview should be initialized inside onCreate like this:

```
public class MainScreen extends Activity {

      String[] cityArray = { "Agra ", "Ahmedabad", "Alappuzha", "Amritsar"};
      Spinner list;
      TextView nam;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
      super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
      setContentView(R.layout.activity_main_screen);

      list = (Spinner)findViewById(R.id.ListView1);
      nam = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView2);
```

And then change this:

```
 nam.setText(list.getSelectedItemPosition());
```

to:

```
nam.setText(list.getSelectedItem().toString());
```

If you just want the index, do this:

```
nam.setText(String.valueOf(list.getSelectedItemPosition()));
```

Answer (score 1):

This is the problem:

```
Spinner list = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.ListView1);
TextView nam = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView2);
```

Move these inside `onCreate()` below `setContentView()`.

Comment: Moved, IDE asked me to change the modifier to final for both Spinner and TextView, i did so. There's still an error, this time related to TextView

Comment: Fixed it, setText was trying to pass an int value into a string value, i had to change the line to: nam.setText(String.valueOf(list.getSelectedItemPosition()));